# Linkedin-API returns insufficient permission and empty result

Tags: linkedin-api

I am making some calls to the LinkedIn API v2 after getting my access token.

Only a single call succeeds in returning `Network Size ok`.

The rest of the calls are empty or permission denied:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:XXXXX&oauth2_access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Follower Statistics:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => Viewer [29398181] has insufficient permission to fetch this organization.
    [status] => 403
)
```

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:XXXXX&sharesPerOwner=1000&oauth2_access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

Organization Shares:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [elements] => Array
        (
        )

    [paging] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [count] => 10
            [start] => 0
            [links] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Please advise. Thank you!